# How to add a class active in a menu where url has the same pass

Tags: jquery

I have the following menu.

```
<ul id="nav" class="grid_16">
    <li><a href="#">FORSIDE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MOBIL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PC OG SERVERE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TJENESTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DIVERSE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NETTBUTIKK</a></li>

</ul>
```

A url path will have under score _ where there is a space.
For example PC OG SERVERE will be

```
 http://www.mywebsite.no/PC_OG_SERVERE.asp
```

DIVERSE will be

```
http://www.mywebsite.no/DIVERSE.asp
```

I'd like to add class="active" in a list with jquery.
For example when you are in http://www.mywebsite.no/OM_OSS.asp

```
 .....
 .....
 <li class="active"><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
 ....
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var text = window.location.href.match(/http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.no\/(.+)\.asp/)[1].replace(/_/g,' ');
$("#nav li").filter(function() {
  return $.text([this]) == text;
}).addClass("active");
```

You can change up the regex, etc...but the concept is the same, get the text, compare it to each `<li>`'s text (since the `<a>` adds none, you can do it right on the `<li>`).  For *much* older versions of jQuery you'll need to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of the shortcut above, like this:

```
$("#nav li").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == text;
}).addClass("active");
```

Note we're *not* using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) here, we're doing an exact match, instead of a substring.

Comment: I hate you. One of these days I'll be able to beat you to answers!

Comment: @Aaron - I sleep for a few hours between 11pm and 4am EST ;)

Comment: Is there any way not using http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.no ? I am using localhost, I am not able to use http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.no at the moment.

Comment: @shin - Sure, you could do whatever you're after, even `.match(/.*\/(.+)\.asp/)[1].replace(/_/g,' ')` for a looser match.

Comment: Great answer. Personally, I'd go for matching against `windows.location.pathname` and `$('#nav li').filter(function() { return window.location.pathname.match($.text([this]).replace(/\s+/g, '_')); }).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

You *could* try something like

```
$("#nav li a").each(
  function(){
    // Could be that you have to use $(this). Not sure.
    if (this.text() == 'DIVERSE'){
      this.addClass('active');
    } 
  }
);
```

But I think it would be better to generate this class in the serverside code.

Comment: You do in fact need to use `$(this)`, since `this` refers to the DOM element that doesn't have these methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathComponents = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var fileName = pathComponents[pathComponents.length - 1];
var documentName = fileName.substr(fileName.length - 4).replace("_", " ");

$('#nav li a:contains(' + documentName + )').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `:contains()` here, since it's a substring match.

Comment: Yes, there could be false positives. But if what's posted above is the entire list, it's not a concern.